# POST http://localhost:5173/posts 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, error-handling

I built a full stack blog using react with vite and express and MongoDB it's my second time building a fullstack app and in the first app they give me the same problem and I tested the backend with the postman and everything works but when I made my react app send API request they give the error that the route I gave not being found.

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./db/db');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes')

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173/posts"
}));


app.use(express.json())
app.use('/posts', postRoutes)


// start server
const port = 5173

const start =async ()=> {
    try {
        await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        app.listen(port, ()=>{
        console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
    })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
start()
```

---

postControllers

```
const Post = require('../models/Post')

const createPost = async (req, res)=>{
    const {title, content, author} = req.body
    try {
        const newPost = new Post({title, content, author})
        const savedPost = await newPost.save()
        res.status(201).json({message: 'Post creates successfully', Post: savedPost })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while creating the post' });
    }
}

const editPost = async (req, res)=>{
    const {title, content, author} = req.body
    const postId = req.params.id;

    try {
        const updatePost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
            postId,
            {title, content, author},
            { new: true }
        )

        if(!updatePost){
            return res.status(404).json({ message:'No post found'})
        }

        res.json({ message: 'Post updated successfully', post: updatePost });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while updating the post' });
    }
}

const deletePost = async (req,res)=>{
    const postId= req.params.id

    try {
        const removePost = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(
            postId
        )
        if(!removePost){
            return  res.status(404).json({ message:"no such a post exist" })
        }
        res.json ({ message : "post deleted succesfully"})
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while deleting the post' });
    }
}
module.exports = { createPost, editPost, deletePost }
```

---

postRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const { createPost, editPost, deletePost } = require('./postController')

// define the routes
router.post('/', createPost)
router.put('/:id', editPost)
router.delete('/:id', deletePost)

module.exports = router
```

My  react

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import axios from 'axios'
import {CKEditor} from 'ckeditor4-react'
// import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
// import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
// import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import React from 'react'


const Add_Post = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
  const [content, setContent] = useState("")
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("")
  const sendPost = async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5173/posts', {
        title : title,
        content : content,
        author : author
      })

      if(response.status === 201) {
        console.log('Post created successfully')
        setAuthor("")
        setContent("")
        setTitle("")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating post: ', error.message)
    }
  }
   const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Header />
        <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}} >Add Post</h1><br/>
        <form id="add-post-form" onSubmit={sendPost}>
            <label for="title">Title:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value={title}
            onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)}/><br/>
            <label for="content">Content:</label><br/>
            {/* <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea><br/> */}
            <CKEditor
            onChange={(e)=>setContent(e.target.value)}
                initData="<p>Hello from CKEditor 4!</p>"
            value={content}/> <br />
            {/* <ReactQuill theme="snow" value={value} onChange={setValue} /> */}
            <label for="author">Author:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="author" name="author" value={author}
            onChange={(e)=>setAuthor(e.target.value)}/><br/>
            <button type="submit" className='add-post'>Add Post</button>
        </form>
        <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Add_Post
```

Comment: The URL you're currently using is for the front-end service. You want `http://localhost:5500/posts`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Well, before you edited your question, you had your Express app bound to port 5500 but now you've changed it to 5173. Your question is now more confusing though... what port is your front-end React app running on? This will be the port that appears in the browser location bar

Comment: both the frontend and the backend running on port 5000 I changed the port to see if the problem will be fixed but nothing everything works but when the front end sends the API request the console give me the error 404 not found

Comment: That's simply not possible unless Express is also serving your React app via `express.static()`. You cannot have multiple apps binding to the same port.

Comment: what do you mean i'm still new to this so the frontend and the backend should be in different ports?

Comment: Ok, so according to the code above, your Express app runs on port 5173. When you start it, do you see the message `Server running on port 5173`? When you run your React app using `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`, what URL opens in your web browser?

Comment: yes when i start the express app the server is running and the frontend too on the same port, and the URL that opens in the browser is the frontends

Comment: I asked you specific questions and you give me vague answers. Do you want help or not?

Comment: I said _"do you see the message `Server running on port 5173`"_. If you do not see that **exact message**, what do you see? Do you start your React app via `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`? If not, what do you use to start it? When you open the React app in your browser, what **exactly** is the URL in the browser's location bar?

Comment: yes i see Server running on port 5173, i start react app via npm run dev, http://localhost:5173/posts

Comment: That simply is not possible. Please [edit] your question to show the commands you're running and the exact output they produce. Screenshots from your terminals would be fine

Comment: Thank you very much you are a life saver the problem was that both the frontend and backend were running at the same port when i changed the port of one of them it worked finally after 4 days thanks man!

Comment: Again, that is **not possible**. You would have received an error for whichever one was starting second. Your operating system will simply not allow multiple apps to bind on the same port. I feel like you must have been missing some sort of error message somewhere

Comment: i didn't have any error indacating that the problem is the port, that's why I didn't know 
what was the problem but you told me that and I changed the port of the front end it worked